# Exported CSV download stuck in firefox

Tags: c#, csv

I'm exporting a CSV to firefox using the following code:

```
string csv = dataTable.ToCSV();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=solicitud.csv");
Response.AddHeader("Content-length", (Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(csv).Length).ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;

Response.Write(csv);
Response.End();
```

However, firefox get stucked in "starting" when downloading the files, my guess is that firefox keeps waiting to receive more bytes, this only happens in firefox, IE works fine, Am I missing a header or do you see anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use [TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28VS.80%29.aspx)

> Writes the specified file directly to
>   an HTTP response output stream without
>   buffering it in memory.

Comment: I'd rather not having to write the file to disk.